# Как остановить выполнение функции?

Tags: javascript

Есть две функции:

```
function anim() {
//тут например выполняется что то долгое, например это функция 
//медленно двигает элемент по оси x слева на право
}
```

как сделать, чтобы при запуске другой функции, функция anim() останавливалась, т.е. элемент больше не двигался.

```
function anim_stop() {
//тут как то нужно остановить функцию anim()
//....
//а тут какой нить код который не касается функции anim()
}
```

Дайте ответ на чистом js

Comment: допустим обе функции имеет доступ к одной переменной, в зависимости от значения которой код функции `anim` выполняется или нет, тогда задача `anim_stop` контролировать значение этой переменной

Comment: clearTimeout()

Comment: На счёт переменной, делал так, но это не очень подходило, а вот clearTimeout() то что нужно

Comment: Остановить функцию как таковую нельзя, это было бы очень опасно. (Представьте себе, что кто-то "остановил" функцию, которая держит блокировку.) Можно только намекнуть функции (через разделяемую переменную или ещё как-то), что она должна сама себя остановить. Если для вас подходит `clearTimeout`, это значит, что у вас не _одна_, а _серия_ функций.

Comment: Тем не менее, clearTimeout, может быть, не самое лучшее решение: знания о том, как остановить серию функций, должно быть локально. Представьте себе, например, что вы хотите по окончанию серии подчистить что-нибудь.

Answer (score 4):

```
var animation = true;
function anim() {
    if(!animation) return false;

}

function anim_stop() {
animation = false;
}
```